# Bash Merging multiple files into single file after reading list of files from another external file

Tags: bash

I have file with the name of `filesList.txt` which contain list of all files which needs to be merged into single file.

```
filesList.txt
------------------
../../folder/a.js
../../folder/b.js
../../folder/c.js
../../folder/d.js
```

Current I am running following commands.

```
cp filesList.txt filesList.sh
chmod 777 filesList.sh
vim filesList.sh
cat
../../folder/a.js
../../folder/b.js
../../folder/c.js
../../folder/d.js
> output.txt
```

RUN vim command `j10` to make above multiline file into single line like this

```
cat ../../folder/a.js ../../folder/b.js ../../folder/c.js ../../folder/d.js > output.txt
```

save and quit file within vim using `:wq`
and run `./fileList.sh` to create single output.text file in exact same order files are listed in.

My Question is what command I need to use to create a bash file which create external list of file(`filesList.txt`) line by line and  generate and single file with its contents. So I don't have to conver my `filesList.txt` file into filesList.sh file each time I need to merge file.

Comment: Do you really need to make this file line-delimited rather than NUL-delimited? (This is a very bad choice for a list of files on UNIX, as UNIX filenames can contain newlines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line-oriented file is a bad choice here (in a "any attacker who can control filenames can inject arbitrary files into your output" sense of bad; you probably don't want to risk that someone who figures out how to create new `.js` files matching your glob can then introduce `/etc/passwd` to the list by creating `../../$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/hello.js`). Instead, separate values by NULs, and use `xargs -0` (a non-POSIX extension, but a popular one provided by major OS vendors) to convert those into arguments.

```
printf '%s\0' ../../folder/*.js >filesList.nsv # generate file w/ null-separated values
xargs -0 cat <filesList.nsv >output.txt        # combine to argument list split on NUL
```

By the way, if you want to generate your list of files recursively, that first part would become:

```
find ../../folder -name '*.js' -print0 >filesList.nsv
```

...and if you don't have any other need for `filesList.nsv`, I'd just avoid it entirely and generate `output.txt` directly:

```
find ../../folder -name '*.js' -exec cat '{}' + >output.txt
```

---

If you **must** use newlines, but you have GNU xargs, at least use `xargs -d $'\n'` to process them to try to avoid other, quoting-related bugs found in stock xargs or more naive practices in bash:

```
printf '%s\n' ../../folder/*.js >filesList.txt # generate w/ newline-separated values
xargs -d $'\n' cat <filesList.txt >output.txt  # combine on those values
```

---

If you don't have GNU xargs, then you can implement this yourself in shell:

```
# Newline-separated input
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  cat "$filename"
done <filesList.txt >output.txt

# ...or NUL-separated input
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  cat "$filename"
done <filesList.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the proper way to do this. I've deleted my answer. Humbled ~!~ .

Comment: filesList.nsv is being supplied - in here order of files listed in this file is important for merger. so it not a good idea to scan directory recursively/

Comment: and for security point of view this is being run on local server only.

Comment: @Developer, then you can use only the part of my answer that applies to you (the very last `xargs` line at the end). Part of building a Q&A base is that often, answers will be used by more people than just the person who asked a question, so it's important to cover things like security not just for that one person, but for everyone who might benefit.

Comment: last line xargs -d $'\n' cat <input.txt >output.txt is not working

Comment: "Not working" how, precisely? `$'\n'` is a bashism; if your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, you'll need to change that. OTOH, `-d` is a GNUism, so if your platform is non-Linux, that may be an issue as well. Anyhow -- if you don't give the exact error, I can't diagnose the exact issue.

Comment: it is only adding one file in output.txt. Yes I am using #!/bin/bash. what should change?

Comment: You'll need to provide enough information to reproduce that behavior; I'm unable to reproduce it myself. Alternately, I've amended in an approach that doesn't require `xargs` at all, and so doesn't rely on the GNU implementation.

Comment: By the way, if there's an error somewhere in the execution of `xargs -d $'\n' cat <input.txt >output.txt`, it should print a message to stderr, rather than just silently truncating output early.

Comment: error message ": No such file or directory" four time as there are four files in input

Comment: but if I use cat ../../folder/a.js it display on line command  which means file is there. somehow it is not reading it.

Comment: your both command doing so. even my following script is doing same thing

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while read line
do
cat $line
echo $line
done < $1

Comment: Sounds like your input file uses DOS newlines rather than UNIX newlines.

Comment: One workaround would be to use `< <(tr -d $'\r' <filesList.txt)` instead of `<filesList.txt`. Another would just be to convert the input file format with the `dos2unix` command.

Comment: By the way, you might run that script through http://shellcheck.net/, and/or see entry 14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls.

Comment: i just open the filesList.txt in vim (on linux) change remove all line breaks and added breaks again. but no luck same error.

Comment: `vim` records and preserves file type. Thus, if it sees a DOS-formatted file when you open something, it'll be a DOS-formatted file when you save it.

Comment: Now, if you want to change file format with vim, run the command `:set fileformat=unix` before saving your file; no need to delete and recreate lines.

Comment: (any reason you're trying to build your own workaround, instead of using the ones I gave?)

Comment: ...to be clear: `xargs -d $'\n' cat >output.txt < <(tr -d $'\r' <filesList.txt)` is what I'm asserting will work around the DOS-newline issue without needing to modify the in-place, when run *exactly* as given there.

Comment: Thanks Charles, It worked fine. you are right problem was because of Dos formatted I used following  #!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        cat $line >> output.txt        
done < <(tr -d $'\r' <$1)

Comment: Might make it `IFS= read -r line` and `cat "$line"` to be a little more robust -- the first change protects against backslashes in filenames (the `-r`), and against trailing whitespace (the `IFS=`), and the quotes around `"$line"` protect against spaces and glob characters within the names. That said -- I'm very glad you've got something that works for you!